# How to copy newline characters from HTML div to textarea in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, text-formatting

Consider the following HTML page fragment:

```
<div id='myDiv'>
    Line 1.<br />
    Line 2<br />
    These are &ltspecial&gt; characters &amp; must be escaped !@@&gt;&lt;&gt;
</div>
<input type='button' value='click' id='myButton' />
<textarea id='myTextArea'></textarea>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myButton').click(function () {
            var text = $('#myDiv').text();
            $('#myTextArea').val(text);
        });
    });
</script>
```

First, there is a div element with id `myDiv`.  It contains some text similar to what might be retrieved form a SQL database at runtime in my production web site.

Next, there is a button and a textarea.  I want the text in `myDiv` to appear in the textarea when the button is clicked.

However, using the code I provided, the line-breaks are stripped out.  What can I do about this, taking into consideration that escaping special characters is absolutely non-negotiable?

Comment: I should add that reading line-breaks from user input in the textarea has always been no problem for me.  It's setting text in a textarea that is the problem.  So far, the only solution I've found is to save the text in a serialized string, but that really feels like a KLUDGE.

Comment: Working for me in Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/8P8fH/

Answer (score 0):

Your code works great for me in both Firefox and Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/jYjRc/

However, if you have a client that doesn't do what you want, replace `<br>`s with newline characters.

Edit: Tested in IE7 and the code breaks. So I updated the fiddle with my suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/jYjRc/1/

Comment: That's interesting.  I rarely even test my code in Firefox because we're an IE-only shop :-( :-( :-(

Comment: Unfortunately, your suggestion of replacing the `<br>`s with newlines doesn't work because `$('#myTextArea').val()` returns `Line 1.Line 2These...` with no indication of line-breaks what-so-ever.

Comment: The solution you linked on jsfiddle does not work for me.  It gets the line breaks correct, but the special characters are not escaped.  This would regular users to not be able to use these characters and subject them to XSS attacks from malicious users.  So far, I'm feeling inclined to just use the serialized string as before.

Comment: You'll have to be specific as to what characters you want escaped.

Comment: I need all characters that may be potentially unsafe escaped.  AFAIK, this means <, >, and &

Comment: Just tested it with all of these characters and new source, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/jYjRc/4/

Answer (score 0):

Do your HTML like so:

```
<div id='myDiv'><pre>
Line 1.
Line 2
These are &ltspecial&gt; characters &amp; must be escaped !@@&gt;&lt;&gt;
</pre></div>
```

And now `.text()` will return the text exactly as you specify it in the `<pre>` tag, even in IE.